# Java Script function not working correctly to replace the name of the selected file on the label tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsfiddle

I am trying to use a code to change the style of the `file` type buttons in html using CSS and JS. Somehow the JS function is not working properly and it is not replacing the name of the selected file on the label. Here are the codes in the jsfiddle: [See the codes in jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/39foaa1L/3/)

Any help is appreciated!

**html:**

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
<label for="file"><strong>Choose a file</strong></label>
```

**css:**

```
.inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputfile + label {
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.inputfile:focus + label,
.inputfile + label:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.inputfile + label {
    cursor: pointer; /* "hand" cursor */
}
```

**js:**

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
{
    var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
        labelVal = label.innerHTML;

    input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
    {
        var fileName = '';
        if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
            fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
        else
            fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

        if( fileName )
            label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
        else
            label.innerHTML = labelVal;
    });
});
```

Comment: There is error in console for line `label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;`. As there is no span element in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no span tag inside your label

Change this

```
label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
```

To this

```
label.querySelector( 'strong' ).innerHTML = fileName;
```

Comment: Here is the codepen link for the same.

https://codepen.io/rachitgulati26/pen/PJbjPE.